Inconsistent results using bindings in SwiftUI
I'm working on a SwiftUI app in Xcode 15.3 that is causing me some angst due to inconsistent success with updating types with bindings. I'm hoping somebody can suggest a fix for the issues I've run into.
My app has a DataManager class that is defined as an ObservableObject. A DataManager instance is injected into the App struct as an EnvironmentObject. The DataManager class has a @Published var projects [Project].
The project type is a struct with several properties of its own, including vars for recipeItems: [RecipeItem] and bakingSteps: [BakingStep]. RecipeItem and BakingStep are both structs with very similar variables of their own, mostly scalars, and each has an enum property unique to its use. They both conform to the same set of protocols, as does the Project struct.
My main view displays a list of Projects, which when tapped or clicked by the user can be edited. My Project edit view contains subviews for displaying the items in the project's RecipeItem and BakingStep arrays.
The Edit view declares its property for the Project to edit with @State var project: Project In its body I display the RecipeItem and BakingStep subviews thusly:
RecipeItemsListView(project: $project,                                    
  hasViewChanges: $hasRecipeItemChanges,
  isShowing: $isShowingRecipeItemEditor)

BakingStepsListView(project: $project,
  hasViewChanges: $hasBakingStepChanges,
  isShowing: $isShowingBakingStepEditor)

The RecipeItemsListView and BakingStepsListView have very similar setups. Both declare a binding to an object to the project: @Binding var project: Project
Each of these views can show an editor view where you can add a new item or edit an existing one. These editing views declare a binding to their respective types: @Binding var item: RecipeItem in the RecipeItemEditorView, and @Binding var bakingStep: BakingStep in the BakingStepEditorView. Like their related list views, they are structured very similarly.
To add a new item, I update an @State property for that type in the list view with a dummy instance and pass a binding to that property to the editing view. For editing an existing instance, I pass a binding for that instance.
Each editing view has a save() method that updates the bound property with values entered by the user.
The problem I'm running into is that adding or editing a RecipeItem type works as expected, and both adding a new BakingStep or editing an existing one does not. I've added logging to the BakeryStepListView where it displays the editing view to add a new item with this code (where cloudIdentifier is a unique ID used by all types for CloudKit support):
        .sheet(isPresented: $showAddBakingStep,
               onDismiss: {
            // TODO: Remove!!!
            print("*** bakingStep in onDismiss: \(newBakingStep.stepDescription) - \(newBakingStep.cloudIdentifier)")

            if newBakingStep.temperature > 0 {
                // TODO: Remove!!!
                print("*** Appending bakingStep to bakingSteps: \(newBakingStep.stepDescription) - \(newBakingStep.cloudIdentifier) for project: \(project.cloudIdentifier)")
                project.bakingSteps.append(newBakingStep)
                // TODO: Remove!!!
                print("*** After appending bakingStep: \(project.bakingSteps.map{ $0.stepDescription }) to \(project.cloudIdentifier)")
            }
        }, content: {
            NavigationStack {
                BakingStepEditorView(bakingStep: $newBakingStep, hasChanges: $hasViewChanges)
#if os(macOS)
                    .frame(minWidth: 400, minHeight: 360)
#endif
            }
        })

After going through the new baking step flow, the console displays something like:
*** bakingStep in onDismiss: Test step - AC18472B-671D-41FD-B3EB-B0384464B9B8
*** Appending bakingStep to bakingSteps: Test step - AC18472B-671D-41FD-B3EB-B0384464B9B8 for project: EF355A3E-3AAC-4DDA-B65B-84C6F2FA7C91
*** After appending bakingStep: [] to EF355A3E-3AAC-4DDA-B65B-84C6F2FA7C91

So I can see that the bound property was updated as expected, and then after appending to the project's bakingItems array, the array is empty.
As I mentioned, the same logic for adding a RecipeItem works as expected.
What's perhaps even stranger is that editing an existing BakingStep does not update the bound item's properties. I can see that user-entered values have been set on their respective properties in the save() method, but logging tells me that they have not been set on the bound item, and it does not change in the list view after "saving" it. Again, the same logic for saving changes to an existing RecipeItem works correctly.
I'm hoping somebody might see something obvious that I've done wrong to account for this inconsistent behavior. I fear I have been staring at the code for far too long to hope that I'll be able to discover the solution. I know I didn't post much actual code, but I'm hoping this approach works better than showing the huge amount of code that is actually involved.
EDIT
I realized that I omitted some important information in regards to how I'm editing existing BakingStep items. That is done from a BakingStepListCell, which is used to display the BakingStep list items.
      ForEach($project.bakingSteps, id: \.cloudIdentifier) { bakingStep in
       BakingStepListCell(step: bakingStep, 
                          project: $project,
                          hasChanges: $hasItemChanges)
       }


The BakingStepListCell has a binding to the BakingStep it represents, and displays an Edit button as well as a deletion button. In addition, this morning I added an intermediary @State private var editStep to the cell's definition. This is populated with the contents of the bound cell when the user taps/clicks the Edit button:
struct BakingStepListCell: View {
    @Binding var step: BakingStep
    @State private var editStep: BakingStep = BakingStep(temperature: 0, scale: .fahrenheit, minimumTime: 0)
    @Binding var project: Project
    @EnvironmentObject var dataManager: DataManager
    @State private var showEditorView = false
    @Binding var hasChanges: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            HStack() {
                BakingStepDescriptionTextView(item: step, hasChanges: $hasChanges)
                Spacer()
                ItemEditButton {
                    prepareForEditing()
                    showEditorView = true
                }
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                
                DeleteButton(action: {
                    deleteItem()
                })
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            }
            .background(Color.lightGray)
        }
        .padding(.trailing, 10)
        .padding(.bottom, 4)
        
        .onChange(of: showEditorView) { newValue in
            // forces update
        }
                
        .sheet(isPresented: $showEditorView, onDismiss: {
            // TODO: Remove!!!
            print("*** editStep in onDismiss: \(editStep.debugDescription)")

            step.stepDescription = editStep.stepDescription
            step.temperature = editStep.temperature
            step.minimumTime = editStep.minimumTime
            step.maximumTime = editStep.maximumTime
            step.notes = editStep.notes
            step.scale = editStep.scale
            
            // TODO: Remove!!!
            print("*** step in onDismiss: \(step.debugDescription)")
        }, content: {
            NavigationStack {
                BakingStepEditorView(bakingStep: $editStep, hasChanges: $hasChanges)
#if os(macOS)
                    .frame(minWidth: 400, minHeight: 360)
#endif
            }
        })

    }
    
    private func prepareForEditing() {
        editStep = BakingStep(bakingStep: step)
        editStep.cloudIdentifier = step.cloudIdentifier
        editStep.id = step.id
    }
    
    private func deleteItem() {
        Task {
            guard let index = project.bakingSteps.firstIndex(of: step) else {
                os_log("Failed to get index of item to delete")
                return
            }
            let _ = await dataManager.deleteBakingStep(step)
            project.bakingSteps.remove(at: index)
            hasChanges = true
        }
    }
}

Now logging shows me that the editStep instance is updated in the editing view. But after hitting the onDismiss closure which is supposed to update the values of the bound step instance, it retains its original values:
*** Saved bakingStep in editor view: Bake: 200° F. for 30 - 40 minutes - () // print statement in edit view's Save() method, after updating values of bound BakingStep
*** editStep in onDismiss: Bake: 200° F. for 30 - 40 minutes - () // first print statement of onDismiss block
*** step in onDismiss: Bake: 400° F. for 30 - 40 minutes - () // second print statement of onDismiss block


Can you include a [mre]?

try using .sheet(item:...) instead, see Sheet

It turned out that the problem was with the Project type's "==" method for conforming to the Equatable protocol that I had written a long time ago when  my model types were all classes. I was comparing lhs' and rhs' recipeItems values, but not the bakingSteps values. Adding in a line comparing the bakingSteps value fixed the problem. Even better, I realized that I could remove the == method from my model types without affecting conformance to Equatable. I also removed the 'hash' method for Hashable conformance without causing any issues. Now I have fewer vectors where things can go wrong if I add another new property to a model type (bakingSteps was a fairly recent addition).

Actually it looks like removing the '==' method caused a problem with appending to the BakingStep array. I have since restored a complete version of it and it's working again.
